# Using nginx along with IIS

Tags: python, iis, nginx, deployment, server

I am trying to deploy a Flask application I developed in an already existing IIS server. The problem is that the IIS version is 6 and is installed in a Windows 2003 server. I tried and failed deploying it onto the existing IIS server.

As a work-around, I have decided to use a Linux VM and deploy the application on uWSGI / nGinx server.

Now, since I have very little understanding of the way web servers work, I want to know if I would be able to deploy the flask application on nginx and link it with IIS? I don't even know if the question makes sense. But basically I just want the same URL that is now used to ping IIS also to ping nginx.

For ex. //TestServer/app1 is on IIS. So can //TestServer/app2 be called in from nginx?

Thanks.

Comment: A page can certainly include elements pulled from other servers.  But you can't have two different web servers responding to the same request.  Give nginx a different IP and reference it for the needed pieces.

Comment: IIS 6 is end of life, if you don't know yet.